# Grouping URL patterns that are similar

Tags: python, django, url

Is there any way to simplify the patterns starting with `<product>` without putting them in separate files?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Basic product functions
url(r'^create/$', 'product.views.create'),                       
url(r'^save/$', 'product.views.save'),
url(r'^save/(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/$', 'product.views.save'),
url(r'^edit/(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/$', 'product.views.edit'),
url(r'^publish/(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/$', 'product.views.publish'),
url(r'^upload_image/(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/$', 'product.views.upload_image'),

# Blog
url(r'^(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/blog/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/view/(?P<content_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'blog.views.view'),
url(r'^(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/blog/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'blog.views.main'),
url(r'^(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/blog/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$', 'blog.views.main'),                      #pagination for main

# Categories
url(r'^(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/category/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'category.views.category'),
url(r'^(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/category/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/category/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$', 'category.views.category'),   #pagination for main

# Content
url(r'^(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/content/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/edit/$', 'content.views.edit'),
url(r'^(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/content/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/edit/(?P<content_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'content.views.edit'), 
 )
```

Just looking for any way possibly to simplify the stuff in here.

Is there some kind of wrapper I can put around all the `^<product>` patterns to preprocess that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi in the django documentation you can find that:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

extra_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^reports/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'credit.views.report', name='credit-reports'),
    url(r'^charge/$', 'credit.views.charge', name='credit-charge'),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'apps.main.views.homepage', name='site-homepage'),
    (r'^help/', include('apps.help.urls')),
    (r'^credit/', include(extra_patterns)),
)
```

so you can do that:

```
extra_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'blog/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/view/(?P<content_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'blog.views.view'),
    url(r'blog/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'blog.views.main'),
    url(r'blog/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$', 'blog.views.main'),                      #pagination for main

    # Categories
    url(r'category/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'category.views.category'),
    url(r'category/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/category/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$', 'category.views.category'),   #pagination for main

    # Content
    url(r'^content/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/edit/$', 'content.views.edit'),
    url(r'^content/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/edit/(?P<content_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'content.views.edit'), 
)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Basic product functions
    url(r'^create/$', 'product.views.create'),                       
    url(r'^save/$', 'product.views.save'),
    url(r'^save/(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/$', 'product.views.save'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/$', 'product.views.edit'),
    url(r'^publish/(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/$', 'product.views.publish'),
    url(r'^upload_image/(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/$', 'product.views.upload_image'),

    # Blog
    url(r'^(?P<product>[a-z0-9\-]+)/', include(extra_patterns)),
)
```